# iOS SDK avcodec_decode_video Optimization

Tags: ios, performance, sdk, ffmpeg, cpu-usage

I've recently started a project that relies on streaming FLV directly to an iOS device. As most famous i went with ffmpeg (and an iOS wrapper - [kxmovie](https://github.com/kolyvan/kxmovie)). To my surprise iPhone 4 is incapable of playing even SD low-bitrate FLV videos. The current implementation i'm using is decoding the video/audio/sub frames in dispatch_async while loop and copies the YUV frame data to a object, where the object is parsed to 3 textures - Y/U/V (in case of RGB color space - just parse the data) and rendered on screen. After much trial and error, i've decided to kill the whole rendering pipeline and leave only the **avcodec_decode_video2** function to run. Surprisingly the FPS did not improve and videos are still unplayable.

My question is: What can i do to improve the performance of **avcodec_decode_video2**?

*Note:
I've tried a few commercial apps and they play the same file perfectly fine with no more than 50-60% cpu usage.*

The library is based off the 1.2 branch and this is are the build args:

```
'--arch=arm',
'--cpu=cortex-a8',
'--enable-pic',
"--extra-cflags='-arch armv7'",
"--extra-ldflags='-arch armv7'",
"--extra-cflags='-mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp -mvectorize-with-neon-quad'",
'--enable-neon',
'--enable-optimizations',
'--disable-debug',
'--disable-armv5te',
'--disable-armv6',
'--disable-armv6t2',
'--enable-small',
'--disable-ffmpeg',
'--disable-ffplay',
'--disable-ffserver',
'--disable-ffprobe',
'--disable-doc',
'--disable-bzlib',
'--target-os=darwin',
'--enable-cross-compile',
#'--enable-nonfree',
'--enable-gpl',
'--enable-version3',
```

And according to Instruments the following functions take about 30% CPU usage each:

```
Running Time    Self        Symbol Name
37023.9ms   32.3%   13874,8                   ff_h264_decode_mb_cabac
34626.2ms   30.2%   9194,7                    loop_filter
29430.0ms   25.6%   173,8                     ff_h264_hl_decode_mb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, even with NEON support, FFmpeg is still executed on the CPU and thus it can't decode faster than that. There are apps that use ffmpeg and HW decoder, my best guess would be that they strip the header and feed Apple's AssetReader the raw h264 data.

Comment: Actually they demux the file with FFMpeg (or internal demuxers) and feed the streams to AVAssetReader or use ffmpeg's decode video if the stream is incompatible. Thus you can play even HD videos (that are not supported by MPMovieController) with 30fps.

Answer (score 0):

just for the fun of it see what kind of performance you get from this, it does seem to play flv's quick but I have not tested it on the iPhone 4

https://github.com/mooncatventures-group/WebStreamX_flv_demo

Comment: Yeah, FLV playback is pretty bad even with SD resolution and low bitrate videos.

Answer (score 0):

You should use --enable-asm optimization parameter to boost performance for %10-15 more.
Also, you must install the latest gas-preprocessor.pl